# Not able to identify Elements inside the Android Calendar picker using Appium or using uiautomatorviewer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, android-uiautomator

can any one help me to resolve android calendar picker selection issues.

I want to select desired date(DD-MM-YYYY) for my automation project.

UI automator recognized entire calendar as one element and unable to get child elements details/unable to get date elements in UI automator viewer.(Screenshot attached for your reference)

Kindly do the needful.

[Android Calendar Picker UIautomator screens shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnm61.png)

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same scenario like this in one of our apps. 
When a date is selected from the date selector the date will be inserted in to a text box. But the selection could not be done through the calendar ui.

As a solution we fired a `date_textFieldElement.sendKeys("10-14-2015")` command in to the date text field. 
That did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.
i am using below command but it opens the calendar picker.
driver.findElement(By.id("patient_dob")).sendKeys("05/12/1981");

Comment: Are you passing the date value in the desired format? In the question you mentioned the format is like DD-MM-YYYY. If the desired date format for the date text field does not met there is a chance that the picker would open.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion desired date format is "MM/DD/YYYY"(05/12/1981). even I met the desired date format that the picker opening.